# Вывод полученного с камеры изображения в виде матрицы в консоль

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame as pg
import numpy as np
import pygame.camera


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self, app, font_size=8):
        self.app = app
        self.FONT_SIZE = font_size
        self.SIZE = self.ROWS, self.COLS = app.HEIGHT // font_size, app.WIDTH // font_size
        self.katakana = np.array([chr(int('0x30a0', 16) + i) for i in range(96)] + ['' for i in range(10)])
        self.font = pg.font.Font('font/ms mincho.ttf', font_size, bold=True)

        self.matrix = np.random.choice(self.katakana, self.SIZE)
        self.char_intervals = np.random.randint(25, 50, size=self.SIZE)
        self.cols_speed = np.random.randint(1, 500, size=self.SIZE)
        self.prerendered_chars = self.get_prerendered_chars()

        # self.image = self.get_image('img/k1.png')

    def get_frame(self):
        image = app.cam.get_image()
        image = pg.transform.scale(image, self.app.RES)
        pixel_array = pg.pixelarray.PixelArray(image)
        return pixel_array

    def get_image(self, path_to_file):
        image = pg.image.load(path_to_file)
        image = pg.transform.scale(image, self.app.RES)
        pixel_array = pg.pixelarray.PixelArray(image)
        return pixel_array

    def get_prerendered_chars(self):
        char_colors = [(0, green, 0) for green in range(256)]
        prerendered_chars = {}
        for char in self.katakana:
            prerendered_char = {(char, color): self.font.render(char, True, color) for color in char_colors}
            prerendered_chars.update(prerendered_char)
        return prerendered_chars

    def run(self):
        frames = pg.time.get_ticks()
        self.change_chars(frames)
        self.shift_column(frames)
        self.draw()

    def shift_column(self, frames):
        num_cols = np.argwhere(frames % self.cols_speed == 0)
        num_cols = num_cols[:, 1]
        num_cols = np.unique(num_cols)
        self.matrix[:, num_cols] = np.roll(self.matrix[:, num_cols], shift=1, axis=0)

    def change_chars(self, frames):
        mask = np.argwhere(frames % self.char_intervals == 0)
        new_chars = np.random.choice(self.katakana, mask.shape[0])
        self.matrix[mask[:, 0], mask[:, 1]] = new_chars

    def draw(self):
        self.image = self.get_frame()
        for y, row in enumerate(self.matrix):
            for x, char in enumerate(row):
                if char:
                    pos = x * self.FONT_SIZE, y * self.FONT_SIZE
                    _, red, green, blue = pg.Color(self.image[pos])
                    if red and green and blue:
                        color = (red + green + blue) // 3
                        color = 220 if 160 < color < 220 else color
                        char = self.prerendered_chars[(char, (0, color, 0))]
                        char.set_alpha(color + 60)
                        self.app.surface.blit(char, pos)


class MatrixVision:
    def __init__(self):
        self.RES = self.WIDTH, self.HEIGHT = 960, 720
        pg.init()
        self.screen = pg.display.set_mode(self.RES)
        self.surface = pg.Surface(self.RES)
        self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
        self.matrix = Matrix(self)

        pygame.camera.init()
        self.cam = pygame.camera.Camera(pygame.camera.list_cameras()[0])
        self.cam.start()

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.fill(pg.Color('black'))
        self.matrix.run()
        self.screen.blit(self.surface, (0, 0))

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.draw()
            [exit() for i in pg.event.get() if i.type == pg.QUIT]
            pg.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Matrix()
    app.run()
```

Класс Matrix должен выводить изображение в качестве символов, в консоль.
Класс MatrixVision должен выводить изображение с веб камеры в качестве символов, в консоль.
Класс Matrix содержит ошибку, или я тупой.
Я не особо разбираюсь в классах, т.к. только учу Python, и этот код я взял [здесь](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwejI7TJ_Y4)

Ошибка:

```
    app = Matrix()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'app'
```

Часть MatrixVision мне не нужна, мне необходимо только выводить изображение в консоль.
Пожалуйста, помогите, ошибка наверное очень глупая, но я тупой.

Comment: Я даже не знаю что вам ответить. т. к. код не мой

Comment: @Cergey2202, ошибка очень простая и в ней все написано: отсутствует обязательный аргумент `app` в конструкторе `Matrix`. И как написали в ответе, вы вызываете другой класс, а нужно `MatrixVision`, который у себя создаст `Matrix` и передаст в `app`

Answer (score 2):

так там где вы код взяли, вызывается не `Matrix`, а `MatrixVision`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MatrixVision()
    app.run()
```

[источник](https://github.com/StanislavPetrovV/Matrix-Vision/blob/main/main.py)